# when use this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None ,ProcessCmdKey can not work?

Tags: c#, winforms, formborderstyle

my code is:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg, System.Windows.Forms.Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == (Keys.LWin | Keys.M))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("LWin M");
        return true;
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
}
```

but the `MessageBox.Show("LWin M");` never work,who can help me?thanks

**update**

the

```
MessageBos.Show("LWin M");
```

just for test ,the real code is:

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
```

Comment: Does `ProcessCmdKey` fire at all?

Comment: @GeraldVersluis if i not use this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None; it work well

Comment: @artwl: Even without `this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;`, it doesn't work for me. It is because the `LWin`+`M` shortcut is minimizing your form. Your form then loses the focus, and the `ProcessCmdKey` is not called anymore. Try with another key than `LWin` (for example `Control`), and you'll see it works.

Comment: If you still want to use combination `LWin + M`, then you should do some OS hooks so that your form doesn't get minimized before catching the event, as @Otiel said.

Comment: Your application will minimize by default right when Windows + M key pressed ? why you want to write code for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with the FormBorderStyle, your code doesn't work when you omit the Load event as well.  The Win + M shortcut keystroke is used by Windows before it sends it to a program.  You can easily tell what it does, it minimizes the active window.

Never use the Windows key for your own shortcuts, you'll need to stick with Ctrl, Alt and Shift.  Even using unassigned shortcuts is a Bad Idea, that will break in the next Windows version.

Answer (score 0):

it depends what you want

if you want to check if "M" or "LWin" is pressed than try the following part:

```
if (keyData == Keys.LWin || keyData == Keys.M)
```

Comment: this is a OR statement. Left Windows key OR M key. artwl wants to have the combined keypress.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. Please edit your answer so that I doesn't get downvoted.